I wonder why am suddenly receiving 100+ subscriber emails a day with strange lettering
I posted a new blog article on my Wordpress site. Suddenly my email client was flooded with many subscriptions to my blog. But look some at the names before the @ symbol. They are flooded with periods:

ea.m.b.ri.s.t.e.r
eam.b.ris.t.er
ea.mb.r.i.s.t.e.r
ama.n.d.a.w.h.o.rl.o.w.1
viane.t.t.fa.l
a.l.haar.s2

I could go on and on. But what does this mean? Was my account hacked? What purpose does this serve?

Nothing here indicates your site is hacked - however it does look like it may have been hit upon by a bad bot.  You may want to use akismet or Cleantalk or a captcha or something to block this kind of behaviour.  =

Akismet has been turned on already, before this infestation.

Wondering if I can turn off the subscription link, or if that is too late. Can't find it so far.

This may be better answered on WordPress.she - but a couple of thoughts - are they coming from the same IP (and if so can you block that IP) and can you add enhanced email address validation?

@davidgo They are all from gmail.com. Hate to block that. I have no idea how to "add enhanced email address validation." I'm not a sophisticated user. I will check wordpress.se.

I never said anything about blocking gmail.   I was talking about blocking the IP of the address which was submitting those requests - ie the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
